# Is it possible for the container to occupy 100% screen height for any desktop screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the container occupy the complete height of the desktop screen.

I can set the height of the `divs` to some pixels and occupy reasonable height.

But if viewed on large screens, the bottom of the container is visible, which is empty space.

Can I make the container occupy the complete height for all screens?

Comment: have you tried height:auto; for the div you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body, div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            div {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Full screen size</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @WarrenSergent-spakatak.com [See this W3C document.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) "The STYLE element allows authors to put style sheet rules in the head of the document. HTML permits any number of STYLE elements in the HEAD section of a document."

Comment: Hi @Jamie - yes - I understand how internal stylesheets work. You apparently don't understand stylesheets though - you've put "html, head, div" - implying that you're styling the <head> element, which you can't do (well, shouldn't do - styling it does absolutely nothing).

Comment: My question was why did you add a head tag to your css, not why did you add your css in your head element.

Comment: Obviously a mistake. Sorry for that, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a sticky footer.

```
html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
}
body {
 margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Read about it [here](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/). here's a [demo](http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you need: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9729opjz/1/)

```
html,
body {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make sure its position is relative to the parent element and give all its parents a height of 100 %. Try this

```
html, body{
height:100%;
position:relative;
margin:0;
display:block;
}

.mydiv{
height:100%;
position:relative;
background:red;
display:block;
}
```

In IE if you do not assign to all parents a height of 100% the child div may not have a full height..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) such as `vh` and `vw` to define dimensions in relation to the viewport size:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

means "make the div 100% the height of the viewport".

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<main>
</main>
```